# Android System problem - Unable to share files, do factory reset

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, factory-reset, system-error, system-apps, share-menu

[image: Android System in download section]I am using a Micromax P362 tablet with Android 4.1 Jelly bean (rooted). This problem occurred a month ago. The app named "Android System" appeared in the 'Downloaded' section of apps. Yet it is not seen in any other app managers (such as Link2SD). When I press in uninstall updates, the app just disappears and all apps hang periodically until I restart tablet. Now the problem is that 'Share via' option is not working and even factory reset option is not working. So, how to make Android system app function normally?

Any help is appreciated

Edit: Another problem is that app permissions are not normally displayed. Eg: Instead of "Internet access", it displays "android.permission.ACCESS_INTERNET"[image: Permissions problem]

Comment: If the app is visible under Downloaded apps tab then it shouldn't be showing 'Uninstall updates' but 'Uninstall' only. Can you share the screenshot of that Android System's app info page?

Comment: @Firelord I have uploaded the image

Answer (score 0):

Apps that can't be uninstalled are apps that come hardwired in the ROM of your Android device. These are typically vendor specific apps or the Google apps.

"Android System" is pretty crucial to your device, so it's weird it's even possible to uninstall it's updates. Every Android device as this, but normally it's not listed. You can see it pop up in your battery usage statistics however, which is totally normal.

To fix your problem you probably need those updates to be installed again, but I doubt that will be possible using the Google Play Store app update system.
You can check, but I doubt it'll be there.

Another possibility is by checking for system updates for your device. 
How you can do that depends on the tablet/os version etc, so I can't help there.
On my phone it's in the settings under "About my phone", which has an update check option.

Comment: Unluckily, there is no software update for my device. And I wonder if a factory reset fix the problem? If so, are there any alternatives to make a factory reset?

Comment: I'm not sure if the factory reset will fix this. AFAIK the reset doesn't reinstall the OS. It just clears all settings and data (OS data, not your data on the SD card) so it's back to it's initial factory state. 
But if some files are damaged, I'm not sure if they will be fixed.
If all else fails, I think this is your last option though. That or install a custom ROM on your machine, but that's a completely different story.

Answer (score -1):

A factory reset fixed my problem (using adb)

> adb shell
>
> wipe data

Thanks for all the help.